# Java Program that reads in text file and compares it to user input

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, linked-list

I'm having some trouble opening and reading in a simple input.txt file to a Java program I'm creating in one of my computer science classes (basic premise of the program is to take lottery data from the file, such as players name and their lottery numbers, and compare it to the user's number that are provided as input). First, when I compile and try to run the program (Eclipse IDE), it cannot see the input.txt file even though it is in the same directory. I have to type in "src/Assignment1/input.txt" in the command line for it to properly find the file. I looked in to the Path utility of Java to see if that could resolve it, but not sure how to implement that code or if there is an easier way.

Also, when the program does find the file, I have my readFile method taking the first number in the text file as the number of tickets sold, and then having a linked list created to hold the data for each person. I am getting a compile error in the second nested for loop in the readFile method shown below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    No enclosing instance of type lottery is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type lottery (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of lottery).

    at Assignment1.lottery.readFile(lottery.java:89)
    at Assignment1.lottery.main(lottery.java:214)
```

I've provided a copy of what is in the input.txt below and my code as well under that, any guidance would be appreciated!

5

Llewellyn Mark

1 15 19 26 33 46

Young Brian

17 19 33 34 46 47

Guha Arup

1 4 9 16 25 36

Siu Max

17 19 34 46 47 48

Balci Murat

5 10 17 19 34 47

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class lottery {

    // Enumeration method that holds constants for how many matches correlate to how much in winnings
    public enum PayOut 
    {
        MATCHTHREE(10), MATCHFOUR(100), MATCHFIVE(10000), MATCHSIX(1000000);

        private int winnings;

        public int getval()
        {
            return winnings;
        }

        private PayOut(int amount)
        {
            this.winnings = amount;
        }
    }

    // Method call to create linked list with purchaser's data in each node
    static LinkedList<PurchaserList> purchasers = new LinkedList<>();

    // Data structure for purchaser information, contained in each node in linked list
    public class PurchaserList
    {
        public String lastName;
        public String firstName;
        public int[] numbers;

        public PurchaserList (String last, String first, int[] nums)
        {
            lastName = last;
            firstName = first;
            numbers = nums;
        }

        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        public int[] getNumbers()
        {
            return numbers;
        }
    }

    // Method to open and read in data from input file
    public static void readFile (String file) throws IOException
    {
        File fileName = new File(file);
            try
            {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(fileName);

                int numTickets = in.nextInt();

                for(int i = 0; i < numTickets; i++)
                {
                   String lastName = in.next();
                   String firstName = in.next();

                   int[] numbers = new int[6];

                   for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                   {
                        numbers[j] = in.nextInt();
                   }

                   PurchaserList current = new PurchaserList(lastName, firstName, numbers);
                   purchasers.add(i, current);

                }

                in.close();
            }

            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public static void compareNumbers(int[] winningNumbers)
    {
        // Creates array to hold winning numbers
        List<Integer> winningNums = new ArrayList<>(); //creates a list to store all the winning numbers

        // For loop to store winning numbers in prior array
        for(int num : winningNumbers)
        {
            winningNums.add(num);
        }

        //For loop to go through each purchaser in the linked list and get their lottery numbers
        for (PurchaserList purchaser : purchasers)
        {
            // Generating list that stores all the numbers from the current purchaser
            List<Integer> playerNums = new ArrayList<>();

            // For loop to add numbers to the list
            for(int num : purchaser.getNumbers())
            {
                playerNums.add(num);
            }

            //Converts list in to a set
            Set<Integer> similar = new HashSet<>(playerNums);

            //Compares set of winning numbers to purchaser's numbers, keeps similar values
            similar.retainAll(winningNums);

            //Calls enum method to look for winning amount based on the numbers matched, returns enumeration
            PayOut matchesFound = matches(similar.size());

            //Only display winnings if matches are 3 or greater
            if(matchesFound != null)
            {
                displayPrices(matchesFound, purchaser.getFirstName(), purchaser.getLastName(), similar.size());
            }
        }

    }

    public static PayOut matches(int num)
    {
        PayOut numMatches;

        if(num == 3)
        {
            numMatches = PayOut.MATCHTHREE;
        }

        else if(num == 4)
        {
            numMatches = PayOut.MATCHFOUR;
        }

        else if(num == 5)
        {
            numMatches = PayOut.MATCHFIVE;
        }

        else if(num == 6)
        {
            numMatches = PayOut.MATCHSIX;
        }

        else
        {
            return null;
        }

        return numMatches;
    }

    private static void displayPrices(PayOut numMatches, String first, String last, int matches)
    {
        switch(numMatches)
        {
            case MATCHTHREE:
                System.out.printf("%n%s %s matched %d numbers and won $%d. %n", first, last, matches, PayOut.MATCHTHREE.getval());
                break;

            case MATCHFOUR:
                System.out.printf("%n%s %s matched %d numbers and won $%d. %n", first, last, matches, PayOut.MATCHFOUR.getval()); 
                break;

            case MATCHFIVE:
                System.out.printf("%n%s %s matched %d numbers and won $%d.%n", first, last, matches, PayOut.MATCHFIVE.getval());
                break;

            case MATCHSIX:
                System.out.printf("%n%s %s matched %d numbers and won $%d. %n", first, last, matches, PayOut.MATCHSIX.getval());
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("None of the players matched any numbers %n");
                break;
        }
    }

    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Asking user for input file
      System.out.println("Enter the name of the file with the ticket data: ");

      String fileName = scan.nextLine();

      //Method call to open and read in data from input file
      readFile(fileName);

      // Creates array to store winning lottery numbers
      int[] winningNumbers = new int[6];

      // Asking user for winning lottery numbers, in ascending order
      System.out.println("Enter the winning Lottery numbers (in ascending order separated by spaces): ");

      // For loop to scan in winning lottery numbers to array
      for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      {
          winningNumbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
      }

      //Method call to compare winning numbers to purchaser's numbers
      compareNumbers(winningNumbers);

      // Close input file
      scan.close();

  }

}
```

Comment: To make a `PurchaserList` you need to do `new lottery(...).new PurchaserList(...)`

Comment: Please conform to Java coding conventions: Type names (class,interface,enum) should start with a capital letter (e.g. `BigPicture`). Method, variable and field names should start with a lowercase letter (e.g. `bigPicture`), and constants should be all-caps (e.g. `BIG_PICTURE`).

Comment: Thank you Zar, you were right, can't believe I missed that. And RealSkeptic, yup I did miss on proper naming conventions, I'll get that fixed immediately. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PurchaserList` class is not static. Therefore, it must be accessed like `lotteryInstance.new PurchaserList()` (because as it's not static, it belongs to Lottery instances).

So, making `PurchaserList` static should fix it.

Comment: Thanks emd, you were right about missing the static, completely missed that it would belong to the Lottery instances. Thanks for that!